# Turn ugly series into a nice approximation

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, special-functions, approximation

I am currently struggeling with a series(actually two). The problem is, that I can do nothing with them, since this expression is so ugly. I would love to hear about any kind of approximations that you could think of in order to have a more convenient form. $(cos(\alpha))$ is a constant and the actual variables are $r$ and $\theta$:

$$ f_1(r,\theta):=\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2l+1}\left(P_{l+1}(\cos(\alpha))-P_{l-1}(\cos(\alpha))\right)\frac{r^l}{R^{l+1}} P_l(cos(\theta)),$$ where $P_l$ is the $l^{\textrm{th}}$ Legendre polynomial.

$$ f_2(r,\theta):=\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2l+1}\left(P_{l+1}(\cos(\alpha))-P_{l-1}(\cos(\alpha))\right)\frac{R^l}{r^{l+1}} P_l(cos(\theta)).$$

Any kind of suggest would be helpful. I do not expect to get a linear equation, but maybe one could write a few things differently, approximate something, do not consider a few terms. Just think about things you would do in my situation.

Actually, I can add another one:

$$ f_3(r,\theta):=\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2l+1}\left(P_{l+1}(\cos(\alpha))-P_{l-1}(\cos(\alpha))\right) P_l(cos(\theta)).$$

Comment: Check your brackets. Is it supposed to be $P_{l+1}\left(\cos\left(\alpha\right)\right)$ ?

Comment: indeed, it was, thanks

Comment: Unrelated, did this come up in anything quantum mechanical?

Comment: no, electrodynamics ;-)

Comment: @Lipschitz. Haha, isn't this the Potential in a general situation problem, I mean solving poisson's equation and all that?

Comment: it is the potential of a peculiar charge distribution and i need to simplify it in order to proceed with my calculations.

Comment: To do any approximation, one thing you should ask is whether there are any small or large parameters in the problem. If $r \ll R$ or $r \gg R$, only the first few terms in your multipole expansion is relevant. If $\alpha \ll 1$, your spherical cap turns effectively into a circular disk, you can lookup the electrical potential for a disk, compare it with this expansion and figure out what terms you should keep. If $|r/R - 1| \ll 1$, the number of relevant terms in your expansion blows up and this expansion will not be a good starting point for approximation.